# How to display richtext data in reactjs or how to convert richtext in reactjs?

Tags: richtextbox, rtf, rich-text-editor, richtext, richtextblock

After fetching richtext editor's data from backend with reactJs the text display with HTML tag inside my div.

**fetched data was such as:**

const richText = `'<p>Hello<strong> World</strong></p><p><strong>Next Line</strong></p>'`;

**Now I want to "Render" the richText in a REACT component as such:**

Hello **World**

**Next Line**

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

`npm i dompurify`

**Step 2:**

`import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'`

***inside your component where you want to display data:***

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:DOMPurify.sanitize(richText)}} >   </div>`